# With OpenLayer3, Internet Explorer 11 not showing an svg based layer

Tags: canvas, internet-explorer-11, openlayers-3

I'm having trouble displaying an svg image in a layer with Internet Explorer 11 (*edge* mode). The layer shows on Chrome and FF. The map itself seems to work as I can see another layer ( a simple `ol.geom.Polygon` created dynamically from an extent) in the same map.

The code below shows the problem. It is derived from the [static image example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/static-image.html) from OpenLayers website. I basically just changed the image source for data URI encoded svg image:

```js
// Map views always need a projection.  Here we just want to map image
// coordinates directly to map coordinates, so we create a projection that uses
// the image extent in pixels.
var extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'xkcd-image',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: extent
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        attributions: [
          new ol.Attribution({
            html: '&copy; <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>'
          })
        ],
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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',
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: projection,
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/build/ol.js"></script>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The layer will show if you browse the fiddle in "IE10" document mode.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

IE11 has a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/925655/svg-image-has-0x0-size-in-ie11) that causes it to set width and height to 0 on an svg image.

Fortunately, `ol.source.ImageStatic` has an `imageSize` constructor option. So you have to know the image width and height in advance, and add

```
imageSize: [width, height]
```

to your `ol.source.ImageStatic` configuration.

Comment: Thanks @ahocevar, but it didn't work. But it did put me on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 indeed has a bug with svg images as *ahocevar* pointed me to.

The solution I found is to set `height`/`width` on the `<img>` object through the `ol.source.ImageStatic#imageLoadFunction`:

```
source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  attributions: [
    new ol.Attribution({
      html: '&copy; <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>'
    })
  ],
  url: 'image.svg',
  imageLoadFunction: function(staticImage, src){
    var image = staticImage.getImage();
    image.width = 1000;
    image.height = 900;
    // Now load the svg
    image.src = src;
  },
  projection: projection,
  imageExtent: extent
})
```